# startSubscription never called in action

Tags: reactjs, meteor, redux

I am trying to use meteor redux middlewares. Following the tutorials step by step, but have not managed to get it working so far. The problem seems to lie in startSubscription: I can never see the get() and subscribe() functions called, I slipped console calls inside that are empty both in the browser and in the server terminal.

```
// actions.js
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { startSubscription } from 'meteor-redux-middlewares';
import FaucetRewards from '/imports/api/Rewards/Rewards.js';

export const HOME_REWARDS_SUBSCRIPTION_READY = 'HOME_REWARDS_SUBSCRIPTION_READY';
export const HOME_REWARDS_SUBSCRIPTION_CHANGED = 'HOME_REWARDS_SUBSCRIPTION_CHANGED';
export const HOME_REWARDS_SUB = 'rewards';

export const loadRewards = () =>{

  console.log("actions.loadRewards()"); // I can see this

  let sub = Meteor.subscribe(HOME_REWARDS_SUB); // I can see this in server console and in the sub variable below

  console.log(sub);

  console.log(FaucetRewards.find().fetch()); // Sub is not performed in time, so this is empty as expected

  return(
    startSubscription({
      key: HOME_REWARDS_SUB,
      get: () => { 
        console.log("loadRewards.startSubscription.get()"); // I can never see this
        return (FaucetRewards.find().fetch())
      },
      subscribe: () => {  
        console.log("loadRewards.startSubscription.subcribe()"); // I can never see this
        let subscription = Meteor.subscribe(HOME_REWARDS_SUB); 
        return subscription;
      }
    })
  );

};
```

There might be some stupid thing I am overlooking. Can someone help me please?

Comment: I was looking yesterday as well into such integration. Can you share a link to the tutorial?

Comment: Hi @cowCrazy! Sorry for the delay in answer. I guess that you already found by yourself, but anyway, the tutorial I am following is the documentation of the meteor-redux-middlewares (https://github.com/samybob1/meteor-redux-middlewares) and the demo of implementation (https://github.com/samybob1/meteor-redux-middlewares-demo/tree/master/imports).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally realized the problem.

First, I had a problem in my store.js file. Specifically, I had deleted by accident the lines related to createReactiveMiddlewares.

> const {   sources,   subscriptions, } =
>   createReactiveMiddlewares(Tracker);

Then, when implementing the actions.js, you have to be really careful about the naming of the actions AND also the Meteor.subscribe method, which has to be named according to the actions. Example bellow, if HOME_POSTS_SUB is equal to "home_randomName", it will not work, because the _SUBSCRIPTION_READY and _SUBSCRIPTION_CHANGED prefixes have to be coherent with the _SUB string value.

> export const HOME_POSTS_SUBSCRIPTION_READY =
>   'HOME_POSTS_SUBSCRIPTION_READY'; export const
>   HOME_POSTS_SUBSCRIPTION_CHANGED = 'HOME_POSTS_SUBSCRIPTION_CHANGED';
>   export const HOME_POSTS_SUB = 'home.posts'; // will work! //export
>   const HOME_POSTS_SUB = 'home.randomName'; // spoiled!! //export const
>   HOME_POSTS_SUB = 'posts'; // spoiled!!
>
> export const loadHomePosts = () =>   startSubscription({
>       key: HOME_POSTS_SUB,
>       subscribe: () => Meteor.subscribe(HOME_POSTS_SUB),
>       get: () => Posts.find().fetch(),
>
> naming HOME_POSTS_... differently will give you a hell lot of troubles
>   later. So, naming the actions correctly has an effect later when you
>   use them in the reducer.js file:
>
> export function home(state = initialState, action) {   switch
>   (action.type) {
>       case HOME_POSTS_SUBSCRIPTION_READY:
>         return {
>           ...state,
>           ready: action.payload.ready,
>           postsSubscriptionStopped: false,
>         };
>       case HOME_POSTS_SUBSCRIPTION_CHANGED:
>         return {
>           ...state,
>           posts: action.payload,
>         };
>       case STOP_SUBSCRIPTION:
>         return action.payload === HOME_POSTS_SUB
>           ? { ...state, postsSubscriptionStopped: true }
>           : state;
>       default:
>         return state;   } }